# How not show on the Table of Contents the subsubsubsection?

Tags: table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

I found this little snippet to get subsubsubsection:

```
% -- For subsubsubsections:
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\newcounter {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection .\@alph\c@subsubsubsection}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

So I get sections like 8.1.1.a. It works well, but the problem is that I see thoses subsubsubsections on the table of content, and I don't want to see them:

[image]

How can I remove them from the TOC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
```

to

```
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
```

(the first mandatory argument for `\dottecttocline` controls the level for the entries in the ToC).

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\newcounter {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection .\@alph\c@subsubsubsection}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\subsubsubsection{Test subsubsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Take into account that you then might need to do some additional adjustments to the levels of `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`.

You could use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to define in an easier way new sectional levels.